# Android: prevent Google Maps from adjusting/moving after EditText input

Tags: android, google-maps, input, android-edittext

I have a basic EditText over Google Maps as shown below

[image]
Whenever I type something into the EditText field, the Google Maps in the "background" will automatically shift itself upwards, like shown below

[image]

**(Note how the Google copyright logo appears due to the upward shift of the map)**

Is there a way to fix this so that the map will remain as is (does not auto-shift) even when I type stuff in the EditText field?

Comment: Post your manifest please..

Comment: Try this approach - just remove the `windowSoftInputMode` parameter from your manifest . OR use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply switch your activity's windowSoftInputMode flag to "adjustPan". Check the official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) for more info.

```
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
</activity>
```

If you are using `ScrollView` add this too `android:isScrollContainer="false"`

Try it..